# IBM Integration BUS v10 get data from WebService input, in ESQL

Tags: wsdl, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm newbie in IBM Integrarion Bus. I don't understand, why I don't see id field (this fileld is in wsdl), in ESQL:

I watched this course: https://youtu.be/uQv6IF4glM4

This is my project: https://mega.nz/#!RFASHYqT!Qb4F93lrCldfWgp0h0BDhAhSPhWWP8vf0jWJTWlKU_4

```
BROKER SCHEMA gen  
DECLARE ns1 NAMESPACE 'http://www.example.org/Employee';  
DECLARE ns NAMESPACE 'http://EmployeeService';  


CREATE COMPUTE MODULE getEmployeeDetails_Request_Response_Compute  
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN  
    BEGIN  
        -- CALL CopyMessageHeaders();  
        -- CALL CopyEntireMessage();  

        DECLARE name CHARACTER;  
        DECLARE city CHARACTER;  
        DECLARE empID INTEGER;

        SET name = 'Emilian';  
        SET city = 'Wroclaw';  
        SET empID = InputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:getEmployeeDetails.ns1:EmployeeRequest.


        SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns1:EmployeeRespone.ns1:name = name;
        SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns1:EmployeeResponse.ns1:city = city;  
        SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns1:EmployeeResponse.ns1:id = empID;


        RETURN TRUE;  
    END;  

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyMessageHeaders() BEGIN  
        DECLARE I INTEGER 1;  
        DECLARE J INTEGER;  
        SET J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.*[]);  
        WHILE I < J DO  
            SET OutputRoot.*[I] = InputRoot.*[I];  
            SET I = I + 1;  
        END WHILE;  
    END;  

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN  
        SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;  
    END;  
END MODULE;
```

Comment: Are you using a [SOAPExtract](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac60010_.htm) node in your flow? If not, you have to navigate like this: `InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns:getEmployeeDetails.ns1:EmployeeRequest`.

Comment: Hello, are you sure the namespaces are correct ? In my opinion, the request and response should have the same namespaces ... But otherwise everything looks fine, except for the maybe missing SOAP Extract node before your ESQL as mentioned above

Comment: upload your project again , its not available on mega.nz

Answer (score 0):

I had to add again type to message type:
[IBM Integration Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkIpu.jpg)